# Code to restrict userform from loading if there is no range to be loaded in combobox

Tags: excel, vba

i have developed a small userform with one combobox in it. This combobox is filled with the range in worksheet upon loading the userform. What i need is, if there is no value to load in combobox, it should display an error "Nothing is there to load". This userform is loaded through a small button.

Below is my userform initialization code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
'LOAD THE LIST OF ACCOUNTS

'ASSIGNING THE VARIABLES
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rng As Range

'Declaring the Variables
Set ws = Sheets("Cash and Bank Account Details")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("newaccount")
Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange

'Adding the Items in Combo Box
For Each rng In rng
ComboBox1.AddItem rng.Value
Next
ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Kindly review and help me with the query.

Thanks.

Comment: `If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then Combobox1.Value = "Nothing is there to load" End If` after your `Combobox1.ListIndex = 0`

Comment: its showing error end if without block if

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you are looking for something like this:

```
If UserForm1.ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Nothing is there to load"
Else
    UserForm1.Show
End If
```

Just before showing the form to the user you can check if there is anything in the ComboBox1 worth showing.

Alternatively, you can even check before initializing the form:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Cash and Bank Account Details").Listobjects("newaccount").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Nothing is there to load"
Else
    'Initialize and fill the form
    UserForm1.Show
End If
```

Comment: It displays the message when there is no account to load but it also shows the same message if there is info to load.

Comment: Which of the two solutions are you using? Note that I updated the second solution (checking the sheet "Cash and Bank Account Details") so there is now also an `If` statement.

Comment: The error is in the first one also the second solution is giving the same result

Comment: Then there is a bug in your original code. For example: is it really the third column which should be checked for possible account numbers to upload? Go into the VBE and execute in the `Immediate` window the following `?Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Cash and Bank Account Details").Listobjects("newaccount").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange)`. It will tell you how many non-empty cells there are in column 3.