# Code to hide/unhide the userform if there is nothing to load in combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I have one userform named as "deleteaccount" with one combo box in it. Upon pressing the button, the userform will load the list from the range. if there is no data in range, there should be an error "Nothing is there to load" and exit sub.
So far, i have developed the following code but unable to find the desired results.

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

'ASSIGNING THE VARIABLES
Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, rng As Range

'Declaring the Variables
Set ws = Sheets("Cash and Bank Account Details")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("newaccount")
Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange

For Each rng In rng
deleteaccount.ComboBox1.AddItem rng.Value
deleteaccount.ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
Next

If deleteaccount.ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then
MsgBox "nothing is load"
Exit Sub
Else
deleteaccount.Show
End If
End Sub
```

Kindly review and help me where i am wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between this question and your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093307/code-to-restrict-userform-from-loading-if-there-is-no-range-to-be-loaded-in-comb Also, you fail to say what you problem / error / bug is (this time).

Comment: in the last question, used the userform initialization but in this i tried to put all code under one button. no userform initialization. this time its gives runtime error and object required error.

Comment: Is the Command Button a button on the sheet or within the userform?

Comment: its in the sheet....

Answer (score 0):

The comments need to switch places (nothing to do with your issue). Instead of `For Each rng In rng` do you want to lop through the cells in `rng` and add to the combo box? What I mean is: you're using *For Each rng In rng* That is wrong because you're using rng twice with different purposes each time. If you know the range on worksheet is one column, you can try

```
For i = 1 to rng.Rows.count
    deleteaccount.ComboBox1.AddItem rng.Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i
deleteaccount.ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
```

Comment: exactly, i want code to loop through the column 3 and fill the list in combobox if any. if there is nothing, then it should display the message "nothing to load" only.